# Pendant la visite au musée, je lui ai demandé s'il pensait de ces tableaux

Tags: grammaire, subordonnées

Est-ce que la phrase

> Pendant la visite au musée, je lui ai demandé s'il pensait de ces tableaux

est correcte logiquement et grammaticalement ?

Comment: Quelle est la construction pour laquelle tu as un doute ? Que veux-tu dire exactement ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si tu dis

> je lui ai demandé s'il pensait

Tu demandes, ***Est-ce qu'il pense?***, *Est-ce qu'il effectue l'action de penser?*.

---

Si tu veux lui demander son avis sur les tableaux, tu dois demander **à quoi** il pense quand il pense aux tableaux en utilisant :

> ce qu'il pensait

Pour donner :

> Pendant la visite au musée, je lui ai demandé ce qu'il pensait de ces tableaux

Comment: Pourquoi ne pas expliquer le possible mauvais usage de *penser de* ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez L'erreur dans la phrase n'est pas sur la formulation *"penser de"* mais sur *"demander si"* au lieu de *"demander ce que"*

Comment: Good answer & +1, but to follow-up on @StéphaneGimenez 's question, you did begin by addressing the other possible interpretation of the OPs example (demander si), but kind of left that behind & jumped to the "demander ce que" interpretation, assuming that’s what was intended. The fact that the OP accepted your answer is good proof that your assumption (& answer) was a good one, but what if he/she had meant “Pendant la visite au musée, je lui ai demandé s'il pensait de(à?) ces tableaux, ou s’il pensait plutot de(à?) la belle Guide du musée?”(but to be fair, you did make reference to 'à quoi')

Comment: The sentence could also be "Pendant la visite au musée, je lui ai demandé s'il pensait [quelquechose de bien/mal] de ces tableaux", that could be correct, but unusual. It forces the author to specify the feeling (or capacity) he wants to talk about. It could also be "Pendant la visite au musée, je lui ai demandé s'il pensait de ces tableaux [qu'ils méritaient d'être au musée]".

Comment: @PapaPoule In front of questions with not much information, usually I do my best to understand what OP means and answer, if I guess wrong, I can correct later. Should I process differently?

Comment: « À quoi » est faux par ailleurs et contribue à la confusion, « demander à quoi » ça se fait avec la phrase « je lui ai demandé à quoi il pensait », qui est différente de la phrase proposée. Ici, on demande bel et bien « ce qu'il pense de » (la question porte sur l'object direct), et il n'y a pas d'autre façon de l'écrire excepté l'insistant « il pense *quoi* de ».