# S'il pensait « à » ou « de » quelque chose ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

Est-ce que dans la construction « s'il pensait + nom » il faut utiliser la préposition *à* ou *de* ?

> Pendant la visite au musée, je lui ai demandé s'il pensait de ces tableaux.

ou

> Pendant la visite au musée, je lui ai demandé s'il pensait à ces tableaux.

?

Comment: Probably helpful: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6987/quelle-est-la-diff%c3%a9rence-entre-penser-%c3%a0-penser-de-et-penser-infini

Comment: La phrase usuelle : "Pendant la visite au musée, je lui ai demandé *ce qu'il* pensait *de* ces tableaux ?"

Comment: The question and/or the example sentence is similar to [this one](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13870/pendant-la-visite-au-mus%c3%a9e-je-lui-ai-demand%c3%a9-sil-pensait-de-ces-tableaux?rq=1), so it might be helpful, too.

Answer (score 9):

Il existe trois formes courantes du verbe *penser*:

> 1. Penser **à** *quelque chose*
> 2. Penser *quelque chose* (pas de préposition)
> 3. Penser *quelque chose* **de** *quelqu'un/quelque chose*

Le verbe peut signifier *réfléchir*, *juger* *envisager* ou bien *croire*:

> - Il faut **penser aux** *conséquences* avant d'agir. (= réfléchir)
> - Je ne **pense** que *du bien* **de** *cet homme*. (= juger)
> - Je **pense** *lui demander de m'aider*. (= envisager)
> - Je **pense** *qu'il n'aime pas conduire*. (= croire)

On utilise donc la forme *penser + à* dans le sens de *réfléchir à*.
La préposition *de* apparait dans le sens de *juger*, *avoir une opinion **de** quelqu'un ou quelque chose*.

La troisième et la quatrième phrase n'utilisent pas de préposition, mais ont une proposition entière comme objet indirect.

De vos deux phrases, seulement la deuxième est correcte. Dans la première, remplacez le *s'* de *si* par *ce que* afin d'obtenir une phrase correcte, comme cl-r a déjà mentionné dans les commentaires:

> Pendant la visite au musée, je lui ai demandé **ce qu'il** pensait de ces tableaux.

Finalement, il existe aussi la forme absolue du verbe qui n'invoque ni d'objets ni de prépositions:

> Je suis en train de **penser**.

Dans ce sens, *penser* est synonyme de *réfléchir, méditer*.

Source: [L'Internaute](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/penser/)

Comment: C'est en effet plus clair, merci. (Je supprime mes commentaires, n'ayant plus d'utilité)